# starting R in windows command terminal

Tags: r

I cannot figure out how to start R in windows command terminal. I run `cmd` to open Command Prompt after I type `R`, `rcmd`, `start R` and try other possibilities I found around but I have an error: `'R' is not recognized as an internal or external command`. I have R installed and I have a short-cut on my desktop and I am able to use it as RGui but I saw people use R in similar manner as python from command line.

I have 32-bit windows 7.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

If it's on your path type:

```
R.exe
```

To get it on your path:

**Start/computer/systems properties/advanced system settings/Environment variables/in the lower box select path/Edit**

then add location of R, mine is `C:\R\R-2.15.1\bin` but likely by default it's in program files.

This is what my variable value looks like:

```
C:\R\R-2.15.1\bin\i386;C:\Rtools\bin;C:\Rtools\perl\bin;C:\Rtools\gcc-4.6.3\bin;C:\Rtools\MinGW\bin;C:\R\bin;C:\Perl64\bin; C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.8\miktex\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\HP SimplePass 2012\x64;C:\Program Files (x86)\HP SimplePass 2012\;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Windows Live;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Windows Live;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Roxio Shared\DLLShared\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Roxio Shared\DLLShared\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Roxio Shared\12.0\DLLShared\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Live\Shared;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Services\IPT\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Pandoc\bin;C:\Program Files\Intel\WiFi\bin\;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Intel\WirelessCommon\;C:\gs\gs9.06\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\LibreOffice 3.5\URE\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin\; C:\Users\trinker\rubytools\bin
```

Then click OK three times.   Now start a new command prompt and R.exe should be accessible.