# Slow R after updating to the newest version

Tags: r, windows, rstudio

I usually run a lot of simulations, mainly statistical ones. Therefore, I use R language most of the time. My laptop has been great till last month or so, my simulations started taking abnormal time to finish. I decided to get a new machine with good RAMs and CPU etc. I downloaded R and Rstudio after I downloaded Windows 11 pro and no other softwares.
I am surprised that this new PC is slow too regardless the cutting edge parts I put in it.

I know for fact that my coding skills not great, yet I have tried my best to optimize the code and lately I discovered that the problem is not the efficiency of my code.

I was complaining to a friend of mine about this situation and asked him to run my code on his machine. Interestingly, his machine managed to run the entire exact code in a few hours while it takes days on my machine. His R version is much older than 4.2.1 which I am using on my PC.

I am not sure if this is the right place to seek help for such problems. Your help is appreciated

Comment: You might want to share `sessionInfo()` of both yours and your colleague's as well as RStudio version (which is not included in that output). I doubt that it is because of R. Sometimes RStudio slows things down, especially if you are using an old/incompatible version of RStudio. Check if your code runs satisfactorily faster in the R console than in RStudio, which is known to be slower. Just open `cmd` and type `R.exe` for the latter (if this doesn't work, you need to [add R to PATH](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14677033/6574038)) and `?source` your script.